# Fundamental Group of $S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology

As is well known, $\pi_1(S^1,x)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ where we can regard the loop $l$ based at $x$ going around $S^1$ counterclockwise once as the generator. Can someone explain why the composition $l$ and $l^{-1}$ is homotopic to the zero element, i.e. the point $x$?

Comment: If you go around and back, it’s like you never left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say $S^1$ is the unit circle in the complex plane, with basepoint $1$.

Then the obvious representative of $l \cdot l^{-1}$ is the map from $[0,1] \to S^1$ which is given by

$$
\begin{cases}
e^{2\pi i 2x} & 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
e^{-2\pi i (2x-1)} & \frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 1
\end{cases}
$$

We can then consider the homotopy

$$
\begin{cases}
e^{2\pi i (1-t) 2x} & 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
e^{-2\pi i (1-t) (2x-1)} & \frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 1
\end{cases}
$$

Notice when $t=0$ this is our original map. However when $t=1$ this is a constant function (which corresponds to the trivial path at the basepoint $1$ (Why doesn't a similar idea work for $l$?). The idea is that as $t$ increases, we don't walk as far along the circle before turning around. At $t=1$, we don't walk at all.

This is summarized in the following picture:

[image: the homotopy]

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 2):

$\ell \circ \ell^{-1}$ is the following loop: you go all the way around, then retrace your steps going backwards. The homotopy to the constant loop works by "pulling" the end of this loop; you can physically model this quite explicitly using a rubber band. Formally (it is much more annoying to write this out formally than to draw it or build a physical model) if we think of $\ell$ as the path

$$f(x) : [0, 2\pi] \ni t \mapsto e^{it} \in S^1$$

and $\ell^{-1}$ as the path

$$g(t) : [0, 2\pi] \ni t \mapsto e^{-it} \in S^1$$

then their composite is the path

$$h(t) : [0, 2\pi] \ni t \mapsto \begin{cases} e^{2it} & \text{ if } t \in [0, \pi] \\ e^{-2it} & \text{ if } t \in [\pi, 2\pi] \end{cases}$$

and the homotopy $H$ from this path to the constant path is

$$H(t, s) : [0, 2\pi] \times [0, 1] \ni (t, s) \mapsto \begin{cases} e^{2its} & \text{ if } t \in [0, \pi] \\ e^{2i(\pi - t) s} & \text{ if } t \in [\pi, 2\pi] \end{cases}.$$

$s = 1$ is the path $h(t)$ and $s = 0$ is the constant path; decreasing $s$ has the effect of "slowing down" the loop so you don't quite go all the way to the end before turning back, and you keep slowing down more and more until eventually you're not moving at all.

This argument is in no way specific to the circle and generalizes to showing that reversing the direction of a loop always provides the inverse in the fundamental group.

Answer (score 0):

Let the generator $l$ be described as mapping $t$ to $x+(\cos t, \sin t)$ for $0 \le t \le 2 \pi).$ Then doing $l$ and then $l^{-1}$ is homotopic to the constant loop at $x$ given by the  map taking each $t \in [0,4\pi]$ to $x$.

I leave the setting up of the homotopy to you. It works since it doesn't matter what point one stops at before turning around, since only the two endpoints need to stay at $x.$